# how to migrate project from android studio to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project built in Android Studio(version 1.2). I want to migrate the project to Android Studio(version 1.2.1.1) in another laptop.

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy your project folder from inside `.../AndroidStudioProjects` and paste it in the `.../AndroidStudioProjects` folder in your target laptop.

All the files of the project are contained there.

Comment: how to import into the target android studio? I am able to copy it successfully but importing still doesn't work

Comment: With "importing" you mean open it in Android Studio, right? Just close your current project or open a new Android Studio instance and open the project from the main screen.

Comment: yes. Gotcha! I was trying to import the project. Then I figured it out that "Open an existing project" was the option. It worked wonders for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> If you are migrate your project from Lower version to Higher version
>   of Android Studio then it will automatically adjust your project
>   according to newer version.

This thing called version compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a standard process ... create a free repository on Github (public viewable) or BitBucket, export project there ... then import the project on the other computing platform.

Not a bad idea in general .. use a version control system even for personal development.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did this process for migrating my other projects and it was pretty easy following this procedure.

Comment: Glad this helped ... using version control is important for developers of all levels!  (Would you be able to mark this answer as "correct" for you).