# How to migrate a project to another machine

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to migrate an Android project developed in Android Studio from one machine to another machine so I can continue working.

I tried to copy the project directory to the target machine; but, when opening the project in Android Studio (<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Open</kbd>) on the target machine, it doesn't load it as an Android project, instead it considers it to be just a directory.

How can I migrate a project to another machine?

Comment: It's a good time to start thinking about using version control. There are free options out there. If your project only lives on your computer, you will lose it eventually.

Comment: save your code onto github.com, or dropbox  then retrieve from same on other box

Comment: If reopened, would be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773258/how-to-migrate-project-from-android-studio-to-android-studio)

Comment: @MsYvette Indeed. I checked age and the other having an accepted answer already. But yes, those criteria are totally valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this problem occurs, only when you try to load the project for first time. Instead of an android project, it considers to be just a directory.

[image]

However, I found a way around, which can fix this issue.

1. Copy the project directory to target Machine.
2. From Android Studio, go to File->Open; Browse the project directory.
3. Expand the project directory and open **build.gradle**. It will complete the required set up automatically and load the project.

[image]

4. Next time, when you will open the project, it will consider it an Android Project.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> So how this can be done?

Copy the project directory.

I usually clean out the bits that wouldn't go into version control (e.g., `build/`, `*.iml`, `.gradle/`, `.idea/`) before importing the copied directory into Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

When opening the project in the new machine in  android studio for the first click on the folder directory and android studio will automatically sync the files and set up the new project.
Select app to include in project.
Next time when you click to open the project it will appear as a project and not a directory.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

*In addition to  Commonwares answer.*

I keep all my projects either in a google drive directory, both locally on my machine and online or on github usually both locally, but always remotely. Anything that requires version control is on github.

That way if anything happens to a machine (which has happened in the past) all the projects are accessible to me.

If I need to use another machine I can download the complete project.

The other way is to copy the project to a removeble drive or usb stick and upload it to your other machine.